# Example of using @ViewTitle with NSFSearch?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I spent all of yesterday trying to make NSFSearch work with @ViewTitle, but I can't figure it out. The documentation has this to say:

> ViewTitle  -  The address of a null-terminated string that contains a
> view name.  If the selection formula specified by the 2nd argument
> (hFormula) contains the @ViewTitle function, then Domino or Notes uses
> the view name specified by this argument (ViewTitle) to resolve this
> @ViewTitle function.
>
> If the selection formula specified by the 2nd argument (hFormula) does
> not contain the @ViewTitle function, or if you are not using a the
> selection formula (hFormula is NULLHANDLE), then set this argument
> (ViewTitle) to NULL.

But I can't find a single example of this anywhere and can't make it work with selection formulas like these:

```
@ViewTitle = "Test Folder" & @Created < @Date(2021;1;1)
@ViewTitle & @Created < @Date(2021;1;1)
```

An example or pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never found a reason to use this, but I've always interpreted it to mean that you can compile a selection formula like "`DocType = @ViewTitle`". Then you can call `NSFSearch` three times, once using "Draft" as the second argument, once using "In Progress" as the second argument, and once using "Final" as the second argument. The compiled formula will run as `DocType = "Draft"` for the first call, `DocType = "In Progress"` for the second call, and `docType = "Final"` for the third call. You get back three results, as if you were searching three different views, but you only had to call one `NSFFormulaCompile` three `NSFSearch` calls

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That's helpful and allows me to see that `@ViewTitle` embedded in an `NSFSearch` formula doesn't seem to be anything more than a generic string replacement. I don't have a `DocType` field, but this now "works": `Form = @ViewTitle`.

What I was hoping to do is use `@ViewTitle` to make a series of `NSFSearch` calls to retrieve documents with a specific created dates from different views/folders. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Yeah, you've got the idea. It acts like a '%s'.  NSFSearch is global to the db. For what you want for folders, I think you're going to have to use NIF calls (most likely NIFReadEntries), and maybe combine that with NSFSearch. I.e., build a list of noteids contained in the view, and then do your NSFSearch and check each hit against the list of noteids to see if it is in the folder. You could do the same for views, but if you know the selection formula for the view you could just append "& @Created <  @Date(2021;1;1)" to that formula, compile it, and just make the NSFSearch call that way.